# Keep rows if there is at least 3 valid values

Tags: r

I would like to subset my data frame based on number of valid values. I would like to keep only rows where we have at least 3 valid values. I was trying to find such topic (I am quite sure there is one) but I did not manage. Brain functionality is very low today.

```
> dput(aa)
structure(list(Names = c("A11DS1", "DDSAI2", "ADDA1", 
                           "TT0FGR8", "TRASD1", "DDAWT0", "YYRRP1", "GFSAX5", "123US2", "FXCH1", 
                           "A3KN83", "A4D1P6", "A5YKK6", "ASDASC98", "ASDASDG6", "A6NFQ2", "GFDAHQ2", 
                           "A6NHR9", "A6NIH7", "P62308"), `116_1` = c(0, 849990000, 
                                                                          1281200000, 1.198e+09, 68748000, 0, 0, 0, 61641000, 43582000, 
                                                                          19723000, 40042000, 428120000, 152520000, 168380000, 0, 228920000, 
                                                                          792460000, 0, 453570000), `116_2` = c(0, 926040000, 1500800000, 
                                                                                                                    1242700000, 48212000, 0, 47242000, 46062000, 30757000, 53163000, 
                                                                                                                    0, 52400000, 463870000, 99146000, 150810000, 31183000, 0, 1.079e+09, 
                                                                                                                    43208000, 421410000), `116_3` = c(742270000, 734460000, 1377700000, 
                                                                                                                                                          1390500000, 52647000, 59797000, 0, 0, 0, 39395000, 0, 43433000, 
                                                                                                                                                          373510000, 143300000, 185970000, 19743000, 0, 931530000, 0, 869800000
                                                                                                                    ), `116_4` = c(0, 553380000, 1478900000, 1368400000, 43087000, 
                                                                                                                                       45608000, 0, 0, 56578000, 38108000, 0, 40301000, 419570000, 153200000, 
                                                                                                                                       174780000, 0, 0, 1064100000, 0, 643450000)), row.names = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  23L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 33L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looking at provided data rows to remove: 1L; 10-13L; 16L, 25L, 28L, 30L.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`  to perform this task. Assuming by valid values you mean value which are not equal to 0 you can do this as -

```
aa[rowSums(aa[-1] != 0, na.rm = TRUE) >= 3, ]

#      Names      116_1      116_2      116_3      116_4
#3    DDSAI2  849990000  926040000  734460000  553380000
#6     ADDA1 1281200000 1500800000 1377700000 1478900000
#7   TT0FGR8 1198000000 1242700000 1390500000 1368400000
#8    TRASD1   68748000   48212000   52647000   43087000
#14   123US2   61641000   30757000          0   56578000
#15    FXCH1   43582000   53163000   39395000   38108000
#17   A4D1P6   40042000   52400000   43433000   40301000
#19   A5YKK6  428120000  463870000  373510000  419570000
#20 ASDASC98  152520000   99146000  143300000  153200000
#23 ASDASDG6  168380000  150810000  185970000  174780000
#29   A6NHR9  792460000 1079000000  931530000 1064100000
#33   P62308  453570000  421410000  869800000  643450000
```

Answer (score 0):

A *tidyverse* solution might be:

```
library(tidyverse)

aa %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(sum(across(.cols = everything()) != 0) > 3)
```

If the "rownames" are needed, then they can be added as a column - and the `> 3` changed to `> 4`:

```
aa %>% 
  mutate(rownames = as.numeric(row.names(.))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(sum(across(.cols = everything()) != 0) > 4) %>% 
  dplyr::relocate(rownames)

# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Rowwise: 
   rownames Names       `116_1`    `116_2`    `116_3`    `116_4`
   <dbl>    <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 3        DDSAI2    849990000  926040000  734460000  553380000
 2 6        ADDA1    1281200000 1500800000 1377700000 1478900000
 3 7        TT0FGR8  1198000000 1242700000 1390500000 1368400000
 4 8        TRASD1     68748000   48212000   52647000   43087000
 5 14       123US2     61641000   30757000          0   56578000
 6 15       FXCH1      43582000   53163000   39395000   38108000
 7 17       A4D1P6     40042000   52400000   43433000   40301000
 8 19       A5YKK6    428120000  463870000  373510000  419570000
 9 20       ASDASC98  152520000   99146000  143300000  153200000
10 23       ASDASDG6  168380000  150810000  185970000  174780000
11 29       A6NHR9    792460000 1079000000  931530000 1064100000
12 33       P62308    453570000  421410000  869800000  643450000
```

Answer (score 0):

**The tidyverse solution, with dplyr , rowSums and across**

The way to go here is with `rowSums(across(column_selection))`, so you can control what goes in rowSums with a selection helper like `matches`, or `starts_with`, or simply by name(`116_01:116_04`), without the need for any additional transformation:

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(across(matches('\\d+_\\d+'), ~.x>0))>=3)
#                         OR starts_with('116),
#                         OR 116_1:116_04,

      Names      116_1      116_2      116_3      116_4
1    DDSAI2  849990000  926040000  734460000  553380000
2     ADDA1 1281200000 1500800000 1377700000 1478900000
3   TT0FGR8 1198000000 1242700000 1390500000 1368400000
4    TRASD1   68748000   48212000   52647000   43087000
5    123US2   61641000   30757000          0   56578000
6     FXCH1   43582000   53163000   39395000   38108000
7    A4D1P6   40042000   52400000   43433000   40301000
8    A5YKK6  428120000  463870000  373510000  419570000
9  ASDASC98  152520000   99146000  143300000  153200000
10 ASDASDG6  168380000  150810000  185970000  174780000
11   A6NHR9  792460000 1079000000  931530000 1064100000
12   P62308  453570000  421410000  869800000  643450000
```